# Is there a way to get the order of dates within one row? (R)

Tags: r

Lets say I have a dataframe with two rows and three columns:

```
A <- c('2019-04-08', '2019-04-01')
B <- c('2019-03-21', '2019-03-08')
C <- c('2019-03-25', '2019-04-28')
df <- data.frame(A, B ,C)

df
           A          B          C
1 2019-04-08 2019-03-21 2019-03-25
2 2019-04-01 2019-03-08 2019-04-28
```

Is there a way to add the colnames by order of dates in the first row to a vector?

In this case:

```
first.row.order <- c('B', 'C', 'A')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the order of column names for each row, then here it is:

```
v <- t(apply(df,1,function(x) names(df)[order(as.Date(x))]))
```

gives

```
> v
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "B"  "C"  "A" 
[2,] "B"  "A"  "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do the trick:

```
names(df) <- names(sort(df[1,]))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
names(df)[order(as.Date(unlist(df[1, ])))]
#[1] "B" "C" "A"
```

If you want to use to reorder dataframe

```
df[order(as.Date(unlist(df[1, ])))]

#           B          C          A
#1 2019-03-21 2019-03-25 2019-04-08
#2 2019-03-08 2019-04-28 2019-04-01
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `setcolorder` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[1, order(as.IDate(unlist(.SD)))]
setcolorder(df, i1)
df
#            B          C          A
#1: 2019-03-21 2019-03-25 2019-04-08
#2: 2019-03-08 2019-04-28 2019-04-01
```